# Operator Splitting methods for DAEs

Tags: operator-splitting

After doing some research, I've found that most of the literature on operator splitting methods (e.g. Strang Splitting, Fractional Step, etc.) are specifically designed for a standard problem type of the form:

$$u'=(A+B)u.$$

In my application, I have a slightly different form:

$$Mu'=(A+B)u$$

where $M$ is not the identity operator.  Can the same methodologies be applied when an operator is applied to the $u'$ term?  Are there any other numerical methods to handle this case specific case there $M$ is not the identity operator?  In particular, I'm looking at a case where $M$ is singular.

***Update***

To put my particular problem into greater context, my operator is

$$M=\left[\begin{array}{cc} 0 & 0 \\ I & I\end{array}\right]$$

and

$$u=\left[\begin{array}{c} u_1 \\ u_2 \end{array}\right]$$

Comment: It would help if you gave us an example of what you have in mind. The situation is different if $M$ is zero for a certain block of elements of $u$. This is then often called a "differential-algebraic equation". The time dependent Stokes equations are an example of a DAE, and it leads to all sorts of complications.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: Indeed I am working on the case where $M$ is zero for some blocks.  I just updated the question with my particular matrix $M$.

Comment: So you can subdivide $u(t)=\{a(t),b(t)\}$ where $a,b$ have the same size? The first set of equations then reads $(A_{11}+B_{11})a(t) + (A_{12}+B_{12})b(t)=0$ which I hope you can solve for either $a(t)$ or $b(t)$ to eliminate one of the two variables from the equations.

Comment: I should mention that this is the uncommon case. In most DAEs, the number of variables in $a,b$ is different and you can't typically express one of the two in terms of the other because $A_{12}+B_{12}$ is not a square matrix and typically $A_{11}+B_{11}$ is square but singular.

Comment: Can't you solve the top equation and substitute u1 as a function if u2 in the bottom set if equations, or am I missing something here?